# Multicolumn layout and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I've searched SO and other sites extensively, but didn't actually find exactly what I'm looking for, as I want to connect clean code with fluid design, that's why this nice article on ALA [named: multicolumnlayouts ] won't help me much.

Page layout goes really simple:  header, container (containing two columns), and a footer. Right column contains the site content and should have dynamic height, while left is the sidebar and contains menu and its height should match the content.
If there is little content both columnt should strech 100% of the height of the window.

I have a code ready with one little minor flaw: the white non-coloroud area below the side-bar. **I just need the sidebar to strech to the footer (see Example 2).**
Pure HTML5/CSS solution would be welcome, but simple javascript would be welcome as well.
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <header>header H</header>

    <div class="sidebar"> sidebar S</div>

    <div class="container clearfix">

        container C 

        <div class="el">element E</div>
        <div class="el">element E</div>
        <div class="el">element E</div>
        <div class="el">element E</div>
        <!-- or more elements -->
    </div>

    <footer>footer F</footer>

</div>
```

Example 1 (little content = no problems):
http://destadesign.com/tag/test7.html

Example 2 (THE PROBLEM is HERE):
http://destadesign.com/tag/test7b.html

Or here with small jsfidde window:
Just add "6uHp8" after normal jsfiddle URL (I cannot post more than two links). Thanks!

Comment: jsFiddle per OP: http://jsfiddle.net/6uHp8/

Comment: what about .sidebar set height:100%; ?

Comment: when .sidebar is set to 100% it streches always as big as the parent conainer (presumably whole window - if body and others divs are set to 100% also), but when content of right column overflows the size of the window and user need to scroll down it's not equal to right column with content and the gap appears below the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uHp8/5/)

[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uHp8/9/)

I changed the sidebar and container to display as table cells and wrapped them both in another div that's displays as a table. Then I set that outer div to have a min height of 100% minus the header and footer. I also removed the floating and clear fix.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <header>header H</header>

    <div class = "awd">
        <div class="sidebar"> sidebar S</div>

        <div class="container">

            container C 

            <div class="el">element E</div>
            <div class="el">element E</div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>footer F</footer>

</div>
```

c

```
    html,body{ height:100%;}
.wrapper{
    height:100%;
}
header, footer{
    background-color:#6FF;
    height:10%;
}

.awd {
    display:table;
    /*min-height:80%;*/
    height:80%; /*edited answer*/
}

.sidebar{
    background-color:#0F6;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.container{ 
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#0CF;

    display:table-cell;
}
.el{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#F96;
    float:left;
}
.clearfix:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I need a minute of peace to check it out. will do it soon (today or tomorrow). cheers, J

Comment: I've checked your answer and I find it helpful (due to streching the sidebar down to footer), but it's not a good solution due to rendering of the page **in Firefox** (v.24.0): **the page is shrinked and not streched to 100% of the window** (like in previous page version without display:table property). See in [your Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6uHp8/8/show/). It seems min-height property of the container div along the display:table property is causing some problem in Firefox (IE10 and Chrome is fine). Do you know how to overcome this? Thanks, Jan

Comment: Change min-height to height for .awd.

Comment: Great. Suits Firefox just fine! One more thing that might prove useful: when you comment or remove the text "Container C" from .container div, then .sidebar's content ("sidebar S" text) drops below the .container's content (sic! / the last element E). This can be addressed by applying vertical-align:top property to the .container; this will work on its content since .container has display:table-cell property. See [this Fiddle].(http://jsfiddle.net/6uHp8/16/). Cheers! J

Comment: Oh yea, when something doesn't align right vertical-align:top is always one of the first things I try.